# Event Viewer - Applications and services log

Tags: vb.net

I need your help regarding Applications and services log. I've create a windows service application, but the problem is that in registry (HKEYLM>SYSTEM>CurrentControlSet>Services>EventLog) the source and log are existing, but in the event viewer Applications and services log is not showing.

I'm using VB.NET here's my code :

```
    Public Const EvtLogSource As String = "MySource"
    Public Const EvtLogName As String = "ExportLog"
    Public EventLog1 As New EventLog(EvtLogName, ".", EvtLogSource)

    If Not System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(EvtLogSource) Then
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(EvtLogSource, EvtLogName)
    End If

    EventLog1.Source = EvtLogSource
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just restart my machine. And my event log shows.